# R table1 package: specify font size and column widths?

Tags: r, ms-word

I'm printing to word and can't seem to adjust my table to fit within the width of a page.
I'm used to printing tables to word using the flextable package (which allows you to specify column width), but can't figure out a way to do this using the table1 package.

Comment: did you see `?table1::t1flex`

Comment: wow I had no idea that existed. Thank you!!